# What is the meaning of "tëuk" in this sentence, and "wizzle" in this other one? (might be Middle English?)

Tags: meaning, middle-english

I'm reading T.H. White's [*The Sword in the Stone*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sword_in_the_Stone) to my daughter, and mostly I can find explanations for the historical lexicon (fewmets and corkindrills and so on), mainly relying on [this rather useful site](http://d.lib.rochester.edu/camelot/text/t-h-white-glossary). But these ones stumped me, and the internet:

"Tëuk" in this sentence:

> "Us be'nt no common urchin" quavered the poor creature staying curled
>   up tight as ever. "Us wor a tëuk when little by one of them there
>   gentry, like, as it might be from the mother's breast"

I'm guessing it's "taken", just from the context. Is the hedgehog speaking a Yorkshire dialect? I read it in my best broad Yorkshire.

And "wizzle" in this:

> If you are feeling desparate, a badger is a good thing to be. A
>   relation of the bears, otters and wizzles, you are the nearest thing
>   left to a bear in England.

BTW I thoroughly recommend it to anyone with an interest in English, historical fantasy, where J.K.Rowling [got her ideas from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T._H._White#Influence), and creative anachronisms.

Comment: *wizzle* is surely eye-dialect for *weasel*.

Comment: aah, of course!

Comment: I agree with you on *tëuk* indicating Yorkshire pronunciation of *take*.

Comment: Perhaps *a-took* for *a-taken*, being a now mostly-obsolete way of using the middle voice to turn a verb to an adjectival use. (If I'm right, then I think the use here wouldn't quite be correct, but whether it's an incorrectly written dialect or a faithfully reported dialect use that differs from that old use of *a*, or I'm just wrong, is another question).

Comment: *Wizzle* meanwhile is almost certainly a weasle. C.f. *wozzle* in A A Milne, *Winnie-the-Pooh*.

Comment: Could also be "a tyke", as in small child. Though that seems to have changed meanings from the Old English where it meant mongrel or cur, so maybe not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Wizzle" is, of course, "weasel," and is probably spelled that way to indicate the desired pronunciation: /wiz'l/ as opposed to /wee' zul/.

I suspect that the "tëuk" is "took," and is spelled so oddly (and with a diaresis on the "e") to indicate the broad compounded vowel common in rural northern England. Something like /tyook/.